# Trying everything to get rid of this error: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Logistic regression model - when I go to fit the model I am getting an error that I can't solve for.

I am working on building a logistic regression model and I continue to get this error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

I have done tests for both isnull (shown in the picture) and infinity and both have come back false for all records. The largest Y value is 10,493 which I feel isn't too large for this to handle. Any help would be so much appreciated! Here is the whole error below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/pt/w87p29y92_z976_m8dv5djq00000gq/T/ipykernel_8727/2148996027.py in <module>
      1 model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
----> 2 model.fit(X_train, y_train)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1506             _dtype = [np.float64, np.float32]
   1507 
-> 1508         X, y = self._validate_data(
   1509             X,
   1510             y,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    579                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    580             else:
--> 581                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    582             out = X, y
    583 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    962         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
    963 
--> 964     X = check_array(
    965         X,
    966         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    798 
    799         if force_all_finite:
--> 800             _assert_all_finite(array, allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan")
    801 
    802     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
    112         ):
    113             type_err = "infinity" if allow_nan else "NaN, infinity"
--> 114             raise ValueError(
    115                 msg_err.format(
    116                     type_err, msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: What image? Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: sorry I was trying to show the results that all variables = 0 for this code: print(data.isnull().sum())

Answer (score 0):

The first steps with a new dataset are to clean it up and to get an rough overview.
You seem to still have unwanted entries in your Dataframe.

Here are some helpful commands to begin with:

```
df.info() # gives you column types/sizes and counts Non-Null values 
df.describe() # shows max min mean and many more stats of every column
df.dropna() # drops every row where one or more columns have NAN 

#this shows you have INF values in your df
count = np.isinf(df).values.sum() 
print("It contains " + str(count) + " infinite values")
```